# Linux: POSIX Timers ignore Thread Priority

Tags: linux, scheduling, posix

I have a Thread which has to run every millisecond. When no other thread of the program is active, everything is fine. But if more than 3 other threads are running, the Timer-Thread is only called less than 100 times per second (on my test machine).
It seems that the priority settings of the Timer are ignored.

I have tested this with Kernel Versions 3.12 and 3.18.

Test code, which prints some values after 10000 calls of the timer thread (so normally after 10 seconds):

```
#define NTHREADS 3

#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

timer_t timer;
unsigned long long val = 0;
pthread_attr_t attrHigh, attrLow;


void TimerTestThread()
{    
       val++;

       if(val >= 10000)
        printf("%i ", val);
}

void BusyThread()
{
    int a;
    while(1)
    {
       a++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_attr_init(&attrHigh);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attrHigh, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrHigh, SCHED_FIFO);
    struct sched_param paramHigh;
    paramHigh.sched_priority = 90;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrHigh, &paramHigh);

    pthread_attr_init(&attrLow);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attrLow, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrLow, SCHED_FIFO);
    struct sched_param paramLow;
    paramLow.sched_priority = 1;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrLow, &paramLow);

    struct sigevent evp;
    evp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    evp.sigev_notify_function = TimerTestThread;
    evp.sigev_notify_attributes = &attrHigh;

    struct itimerspec value;
    value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;           // Interval
    value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 1000000;
    value.it_value.tv_sec = 0;              // Initial Expiration
    value.it_value.tv_nsec = 1000000;

    int i;
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    for(i=0; i<NTHREADS;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(threads[i]), &attrLow, BusyThread, NULL);
    }

    if(timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &evp, &timer) != 0)
    {
        i = 5;
    }
    if(timer_settime(timer, 0, &value, NULL) != 0)
    {
        i = 6;
    }

    while(1);
}
```

I do not understand why the behavior is like this. Maybe you see something i missed.

EDIT: Corrected a silly source copy error

Comment: How did you determine that it was running at a lower frequency? also, have you tried adding a newline to your `printf()` call (as stdout is usually line buffered). You might also want to check `timer_getoverrun()` to see if overruns occurred in that time period (i.e. timer was supposed to trigger some number of times, but didn't due to delays, overhead, etc.)